# Plotting confidence intervals on tsline plot

Tags: time, time-series, stata, transformation

I am attempting to plot a time series in Stata and need to add in the 95% confidence intervals (+- 1.96) (see picture) but I cannot work out the code.

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlWJd.png)

```
regress CSAD Market_IndexABS MISq Lag1_CSAD Lag2_CSAD Lag3_CSAD

predict resid_std, rstandard

twoway (tsline resid_std, title("Standardized Residuals Plot")) (rcap -1.96 resid_std time, lcolor(red)) (rcap 1.96 resid_std time, lcolor(red))
```

I am getting the error code - invalid name
r(198);

Answer (score 0):

```
twoway (tsline resid_std, ///
title("Standardized Residuals Plot")) /// 
(rcap -1.96 resid_std time, lcolor(red)) (rcap 1.96 resid_std time, lcolor(red))
```

I can't test this, but I think it's a start.

```
twoway tsline resid_std, title("Standardized Residuals Plot")
```

The rest of the syntax is just a wild guess at what might work, is it not?

`rcap` needs three variables.

What you need is possibly closer to this

```
gen upper = whatever + 1.96 * se 
gen lower = whatever - 1.96 * se
```

and then a call to

```
rcap upper lower time, lcolor(red)
```

So the whole thing may have this flavour

```
twoway tsline resid_std, title("Standardized Residuals Plot") || rcap upper lower time, lcolor(red)
```

I advise against the `()` syntax for different `twoway` commands. There are enough parentheses to keep track of otherwise.

`whatever` should perhaps be `resid_std`.

Whether `se` is to replaced with a variable name or a constant is something I can't tell you.

IMPORTANT DETAIL This is all avoiding the statistical question of whether what you are trying makes sense. Usually confidence intervals are associated with predicted values. I have never heard about residuals being supplied with confidence intervals.